# Cut paper using minimum number of cuts

Tags: algorithm, puzzle

There is an m × n rectangular board drawn on a  graph paper. You need to cut it into mn 1 × 1 squares by straight cuts along the grid lines. You are allowed to stack several pieces together to cut them at the same time, which is considered one cut. Design an algorithm that performs this task with the minimum number of cuts. any help is appreciated

Comment: Can you fold? Or only stack already separated pieces of paper?

Comment: no just stack several pieces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that every cut will be along grid lines, and that instead of moving the knife we can always move the paper to the desired cut location. This means that if we have a bunch of pieces of paper we can always move and stack each paper such that we can cut in a desired location independently on each paper.

Therefore solving the problem for *m x n* can be done recursively in a minimax approach. Let *o(m, n)* be the number of cuts needed in the optimal method. Then optimal cut is the one that gives us two pieces of paper, of size *a x b* and *c x d*, such that maximum the number of cuts for both of them is minimized. We can always cut them in parallel (as we've seen above), so that's why only the maximum and not the sum of their optimal cuts counts.

Finally note that we can only cut either the *m* or the *n*, not both at the same time. With these observations we can write an recurrence (I use Python):

```
import functools

@functools.lru_cache(None)  # Memoize solution.
def o(m, n):
    if m == n == 1: return 0
    cut_candidates =  [((k, n), (m-k, n)) for k in range(1, m)]
    cut_candidates += [((m, k), (m, n-k)) for k in range(1, n)]
    return 1 + min(max(o(a, b), o(c, d))
                   for (a, b), (c, d) in cut_candidates)
```

And by memoizing we can do dynamic programming on `m, n`, which I did above. Looking up the results of this function we find the correct sequence [A096198](http://oeis.org/A096198). We also find that there's a much simpler solution, namely `ceil(log2(m)) + ceil(log2(n))`.